# Get-adcomputer field into variable includes cr/lf

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the computers distinguished name, set it into a variable `$dname`
Then I can use the disable computer command  `disable-adaccount -Identity $dname`

`$hostname` is set OK as `"WIN10TEST1"`
When using this command

```
$dname = (Get-ADcomputer -Identity "$hostname" | select DistinguishedName | ft -hide)
```

It fails like this:

```
disable-adaccount -Identity $dname
```

> Disable-ADAccount : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount' required by parameter
>   'Identity'. Specified method is not supported. At line:1 char:29
>   + disable-adaccount -Identity $dname
>   +                             ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Disable-ADAccount], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.DisableADAccount

If I set the variable manually

```
$dname=CN=WIN10TEST1,OU=Workstations,DC=somedomain,DC=local
disable-adaccount -Identity $dname
```

It works OK so its a problem with the variable coming in.

When examining the returned data in `$dname` it comes back with a `cr/lf` before and after the data I need. I think this is tripping it up.

```
$hostname = "WIN10TEST1"
$dname = (Get-ADcomputer -Identity "$hostname" | select DistinguishedName | ft -hide)
disable-adaccount -Identity $dname
```

Note: Check `$dname`.....it returns with `cr/lf` before/after data

I expect to get the `distinquishedname` string with no other data

```
CN=WIN10TEST1,OU=Workstations,DC=somedomain,DC=local
```

Comment: DO NOT use FT or any of the `Format-*` cmdlets for ANYTHING other than FINAL output to the screen or a plain text file. they DO NOT return standard objects - instead they return butchered bits of your items wrapped in formatting code.

Comment: After playing around with this and some wmi options, I'm realizing no matter what I do the varible $dname is not getting set. Is there any reason other variables work but not this one? Do you need to define the variable , or number of variables in the code or something?

Comment: what is your current code? you still show _only_ the known defective `FT` code ...

Answer (score 1):

As @Lee_Dailey mentions, there is no need to use Select, or Format Table on anything because they are meant for **display only**, and will mess with your data in unintended ways if you save that formatted data to a variable.

With Active Directory PowerShell module you can simply pass the Computer object to [Disable-ADAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/disable-adaccount), and it knows how to identify and handle it:

```
$computer = Get-ADcomputer -Identity "$hostname"
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $computer
```

Comment: this `Select, or Format Table on anything because they are meant for display only` aint quite correct. [*grin*] the `Select-Object` stuff _is_ for working with objects ... on the `Format-*` cmdlets are intended for final screen display OR final output to aplain text file.

Comment: Hi Hal, without the select, all the fields return for that computer object. I only want the DistinquishedName as the disable-Adaccount  only supports a few fields.  Is there another way to get this field?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You technically don't need to have `Get-ADComputer` to get the computer account. If you have a list of machines, you can simply pass the SAM account names to `Disable-ADAccount` directly. You don't need to pass the distinguished name exclusively.